# How find this maximum $x+y$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

let $x,y\in [0,2\pi]$, and $2\sin{x}\cos{y}+\sin{x}+\sin{y}+\dfrac{1}{2}=0$,find the maximum $x+y$

my idea
$$\sin{x}+\sin{y}=2\sin{\dfrac{x+y}{2}}\cos{\dfrac{x-y}{2}}$$

Comment: Have you seen the method of Lagrange Multipliers? What is your most recent math course or level?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't like this Lagrange Multipliers all time,

Comment: @math110 : I am troubled by no reply of you to my answer. I think the civilized people use to answer such things.

Answer (score 1):

Let us change $t=x-y,\, s= x+y.$ Then your problem is written in terms of $s$ and $t$ as follows .

Maximize $s$ 
under the constraints $$ \left\{\sin(s) +\sin(t) +2\sin\left(\frac s 2 \right) \cos\left(\frac t 2\right)= \frac 1 2 , 0 \le s, s \le 4\pi, -2\pi \le t,\,t \le2\pi \right\}. $$
It remains to put $s=4\pi$ and to solve the equation $\sin(t) = \frac 1 2$ and  to return to $x$ and $y$. I leave it on your own, stating the answer $y=2\pi,\, x= 2\pi-  \pi /6 .$ The numerical calculations confirm that result.